# Any way to config the apk's host IP to my local IP

Tags: android, go

I am trying to setup the app in this project.
https://github.com/Kirk-Wang/nanoserver

I have successfully setup the database and can view in http://localhost:8080/
However, when I try to map remote to the ip port it provided in appConfig.luac(decompiled mahjong.apk to obtain), the app still cannot connect to my local server. I used 'ipconfig' command to get the IPv4 address which is 192.168.0.102 and use Charles map remote function to handle the mapping.

Any method can I check the local port is available to host the app or the mapping is correct ?

Comment: I'm assuming this server is running on your PC, and the android app is running on an emulator or device?  In that case, you cant view it from localhost at all, because the emulator/device isn't on the same virtual machine.  If its an emulator, you can use 10.0.2.2.  If it's an actual device, you have to use the real IP, it has to be on the same wifi network, and you need to poke a hole in your firewall in the router.  Or you need a public IP, which isn't going to happen.  Or you need to put it up in the cloud on a cheap/free host.

Comment: Use map remote to 10.0.2.2:12307 instead ? Maybe I need to use android studio to be an debugger for checking the error.

Comment: If you're on an emulator, no need to remap anything-  just use 10.0.2.2 as the IP address, with whatever port its running on (8080 here).

Comment: But the appConfig.luac is using the ip of project owner, how can I change it  to 10.0.2.2?  luac file is already compiled and cannot decompile.